Is there an approved way to play Genshin Impact with a controller on Android?
Since Genshin Impact came out, a lot of forum questions and articles popped up about playing the game on Android using a controller. A few years ago, all the answers were like "only the console, PC and iOS versions of the game support a controller", which was quite disappointing. From what I understand, the reason is that users could use external Bluetooth devices to cheat at the game.
I looked it up again recently and the results seem to have changed: different articles and Reddit threads mention using a third-party app like Mantis or the Razer Kishi to map controller inputs to the game.
To me that sounds like a good solution, however people say (Reddit, HoYoverse forums) that you can and will get banned for using such an app.
I would like to know if this is real, if anyone here succeeded in finding a way to play Genshin Impact with a controller.
Owning a powerful Android tablet, I would be very happy to play the game on it as I barely use my computer these days.

I guess that no application developer ever said "You are free to use applications that can manipulate the game in a way unintended by the developer". This is a default statement in (bigger) game devs TOS. Can you answer that question: Is a keyboard driver a input manipulating software? Then replace keyboard with controller

Have you tried searching for info about this controller? It states to be "officially licensed" so that could be an option.

@Ꮢedacted Yes, but the Amazon page specifically mentions: Compatible with Windows PC, Steam Deck, Raspberry Pi and Android devices. (The Android version of Genshin Impact does not support external controller.)

@ChrᴉzremembersMonica I'm not sure I follow. This may be the rule but the editor may ban arbitrarily if they think otherwise.

@C.Crt then... I fear that the other option is using a PS5 as your smartphone. Probably easier and you don't  risk getting banned after spending on the gacha.

@Ꮢedacted Yup, that's what I feared. But thanks a lot for your efforts.

@C.Crt technically, you could stream the game on your device from the GeForce platform. This solves all your issues: GeForce offers controller binding support, should be officially supported (there are even some documented replies from the Hoyoverse Customer Support stating that you can use the GeForce key binding) and since you stream the game you won't have disk space issues either. Yet, you get two new problems: first, you want an unlimited data plan and second you have to pay the GeForce subscription.
